# Rails: Translation for submit button on form which posts to custom action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-i18n

I have a `TicketController`, with a custom action called `postpone`. I would like to have custom translations on the submit button on the rails_bootstrap_form for this action. I'd like the submit button to read 'Postpone until' rather than 'Submit'. Despite adding translations to my `en.yml` locale, I18n reports they are missing. Where have I gone wrong?

This is on Rails 4.2.7, with rails-i18n 4.0.9, and bootstrap_form 2.5.2.

Form:

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @ticket, url: postpone_ticket_path(@ticket) do |h| %>
    <%= h.datetime_select :postpone_date %>
    <%= h.submit t("helpers.submit.ticket.postpone") %>
<% end %>
```

en.yml

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      ticket:
        postpone: 'Postpone until'
```

Comment: Do you use i18n in other places, and is it working there? In other words, is your i18n setup working?

Comment: Yes it is. It's working on model attribute translations and various other items.

Comment: If you view source on the rendered page, you should see something like this: <span class="translation_missing" title="translation missing: en.helpers.submit.ticket.postpone">Postpone</span> Make sure Rails is looking for the string you think it should be. You can also set "config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true" in your development.rb file to have Rails raise an error instead of failing quietly.

Comment: It says precisely: translation missing: en.helpers.submit.ticket.postpone.  Which is precisely what I have in the yml, right? I'll try raising the errors though, thanks for the tip.